# Passing an array of structures to a Perl 6 NativeCall function

Tags: raku, nativecall

I'm trying to use NativeCall to interact with some C functions.

I have a simple C struct, and a function that wants an array of them.

```
struct foo {
    int x;
    char *s;
};

struct foo foo_array[3];

foo_array[0].x = 12;
foo_array[0].s = "foo";
foo_array[1].x = 27;
foo_array[1].s = "bar";
foo_array[2].x = -1;

void somefunc(foo_array);
```

I've tried a bunch of ways, but can't seem to get it quite right.

```
class foo is repr('CStruct') {
    has int32 $.x;
    has Str $.s
};

sub somefunc(CArray[foo]) is native { * }

my @foo-array := CArray[foo].new;

@foo-array[0] = ???
@foo-array[1] = ???
@foo-array[2] = ???

somefunc(@foo-array);
```

How do I properly create an object of class foo and set their values,
and how do I make an array of them suitable for passing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, there's no built-in way to do this. However, there's enough rope to <del>hang yourself</del> *build a workaround*:

```
role StructArray[Mu:U \T where .REPR eq 'CStruct'] does Positional[T] {
    has $.bytes;
    has $.elems;

    method new(UInt \n) {
        self.bless(bytes => buf8.allocate(n * nativesizeof T), elems => n);
    }

    method AT-POS(UInt \i where ^$!elems) {
        nativecast(T, Pointer.new(nativecast(Pointer, $!bytes) + i * nativesizeof T));
    }

    method pointer {
        nativecast(Pointer[T], $!bytes);
    }
}
```

This should allow the following to work:

```
my @foo-array := StructArray[foo].new(10); # 'array' with 10 elements
@foo-array[0].x = 42;
```

Interaction with C functions is possible by passing `@foo-array.pointer` to a parameter of type `Pointer[foo]`. As structures are passed by pointer as well, you could also pass `@foo-array[0]` to a parameter of type `foo` for the same effect.

Comment: That lets me assign to my int32 with @foo-array[0].x = 42, but I get "Cannot modify an immutable Str" for the Str.

Comment: @CurtTilmes: there are at least two ways to get around this: (1) write a C function that does the assignment (2) use a pointer-sized integer as a pointer substitute to which you assign `+nativecast(Pointer, "???".encode)`; in either case, care has to be taken so that the gc won't collect the objects while they are in use on the C side

Comment: I changed it from 'Str' to 'size_t' and set it to nativecast(Pointer, CArray[uint8].new($mystring.encode)).Int  That seems to work.  I'll try it without the CArray.

Comment: +nativecast(Pointer, $mystring.encode) doesn't nul terminate the string.  +nativecast(Pointer, CArray[uint8].new($mystring.encode)) works.

Comment: you could manually terminate the string, eg `"$mystring\0".encode` should do it; you should also store the `CArray` if you go with your version (or the buffer returned by `encode` in mine) in some variable to keep it alife as long as you need it

Comment: Yep, I just did that.  Works fine.  I will ensure the variables are marked in use long enough that the GC won't mess with them.

Comment: Thank you.  I understand this a bit better now.

Answer (score 2):

The following code shows how to pass a pointer to byte and pointer to wchar to a windows api function.

I didn't have a case yet where I need to pass in an array of structures, but I don't see why the same technique would not apply. Most important: You must make sure you allocate memory for your data!

```
use NativeCall;

constant UINT    := uint32;
constant BOOL    := uint32;
constant BYTE    := uint8;
constant WCHAR   := uint16;
constant int     := int32;

constant LPWTSTR      := CArray[WCHAR];
constant PBYTE        := CArray[BYTE];

my $virtual-keycode = 0xBC; # comma

sub SetConsoleCP(UINT) is native('Kernel32') returns BOOL { * };
sub SetConsoleOutputCP(UINT) is native('Kernel32') returns BOOL { * };

# winapi: int ToUnicode( UINT wVirtKey, UINT wScanCode, const PBYTE lpKeyState, LPWSTR pwszBuff, int cchBuff, UINT wFlags );
sub ToUnicode(UINT, UINT, PBYTE is rw, LPWTSTR is rw, int32, UINT) is native("User32") returns int32 { * };

my @kbs := CArray[BYTE].new(0 xx 256);
my @buf := CArray[WCHAR].new(0 xx 2);

say "Can't set Codepage" unless SetConsoleCP(65001) && SetConsoleOutputCP(65001);

say "Got Unicode" ~ @buf[0] ~ " -> " ~ @buf[0].chr
    if ToUnicode( $virtual-keycode, 0, @kbs, @buf, 2 ,0);
```