# How to pass a CArray[ of-struct] from Raku to C?

Tags: raku, nativecall

How do I make this work?

Update:  After searching Github, which includes the Raku spec-test, and here, I haven't found any examples of passing a CArray[of-structs].  [Here there is a post by Christoph](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43554058/1077672) from 2017 which gives a "work around".

Christoph's solution likely works but would be better in NativeCall, if there is nothing better.

On Github there is [a Rakudo test that uses a `int TakeAStructArray(Struct **structs)`](https://github.com/search?q=%22int+TakeAStructArray%22&type=Code), which might help if you can write a C function to repackage its args to forward to a `TakeAnArrayOfStruct( struct Struct[])`.

Below, JJMerelo seconds my suspicion that this fails due to a bug in Rakudo.

I have a **C** function that uses a timespec struct similar to that  used
in the NativeCall docs:

struct TS {

int show2( struct TS ts[2] ) {
printf( "show2: (1)  %ld %ld  (2) %ld %ld\n",
ts[0].ot, ts[0].one, ts[1].ot, ts[1].one);
return 0;
}
which works fine when called from **C**.

Calling from Raku (moar) doesn't work:

```
class TS is repr('CStruct') {
    has long $.ot;
    has long $.one;
}

sub show2( CArray[TS] --> int32) is native(
    '/home/rir/Raku/try-CArray/libshow.so'
    ) {*}

my $A = CArray[TS].new;
$A[1] = TS.new( :ot(50), :one(60));
$A[0] = TS.new( :ot(30), :one(40));
show2( $A);
say "  s/b 30 40 50 60\n";
```

No errors, just results like:

```
show2: (1)  94658691693328 94658695469968  (2) 0 0
  s/b 30 40 50 60
```

Analogous functions `int show2long( long i[2] )`
and `int showTS(int show1( struct TS *ts )` work.

Comment: Can you please edit to show the timespec struct you're using? While the original uses an uint8 and a long, yours seem to use two long ints. Besides, the name is different. Just include the header where you took it from, or the actual definition.

Comment: I would say this looks like a bug. Apparently, all data is stashed into the first element of the array.

Answer (score 7):

I had this exact problem a while ago, which forced me to write [a workaround](https://github.com/Xliff/p6-GLib/blob/master/lib/GLib/Roles/TypedBuffer.pm6)

Short answer, this isn't yet supported in NativeCall.

Long answer: As stated above, there is a workaround. If you don't want to browse my code, the answer boils down to this:

Use a `Pointer`.

Or, better yet, a Buf and then use NativeCall::Blob's `pointer-to`.

You would then use the following routine to access the elements as a positional:

```
  # Cribbed from MySQL::Native. Thanks, ctilmes!
  method AT-POS(Int $field) {
    nativecast(
      T,
      Pointer.new( $!b + $field * nativesizeof(T) )
    )
  }
```

And the following method to assign a struct at the proper index

```
  method bind (Int() $pos, T $elem) {
    my uint64 $p = $pos;

    memcpy(
      Pointer.new( $!b + $p * nativesizeof(T) ),
      nativecast(Pointer, $elem),
      nativesizeof(T)
    );
  }
```

So a bare bones implementation of such a thing would be:

```
use NativeHelper::Blob;

class TypedBuffer {
  has Buf $!b;

  submethod BUILD ( :@array-of-structs ) {
    # Assumes that array contains homogeneous struct values!
    $!b = Buf.allocate(
      @array-of-structs.elems * nativesizeof( @a[0].WHAT )
    )
  }    

  method new (@array-of-structs) {
    self.bless( :@array-of-structs); 
  }

  method bind (Int() $pos, T $elem) {
    my uint64 $p = $pos;

    memcpy(
      Pointer.new( $!b + $p * nativesizeof(T) ),
      nativecast(Pointer, $elem),
      nativesizeof(T)
    );
  }

  method AT-POS(Int $field) {
    nativecast(
      T,
      Pointer.new( $!b + $field * nativesizeof(T) )
    )
  }

  method Pointer {
    pointer-to($!b);
  }

}
```

Basic usage would then be:

```
my $aos = TypedBuffer.new(@array-of-structs);  # Init
my $struct = $aos[0];                          # Retrieve first element
$aos.bind(2, $new-struct);                     # Replace third element
my-c-func($aos.Pointer);                       # Make call to a C Function
```

Comment: May I use this in a GPLed module?  And push it to the Raku repo to inspire a fix there (I'd think it could be better done in NQP)?

Comment: @rir - No problem. If you would like help with maintenance and development, I would be happy to help.